# Android ListView Buffer

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, buffer, adapter

My previous implementation of my list was a simple LinearLayout inside a ScrollView filled with my items.

I switched to the Android implementation of a ListView to simply use the CursorAdapter. Everything works but there is one issue that drives me nuts.

My items consists of some TextViews and one ImageView. I load the Image from the Internet or my local ImageCache. But even with the ImageCache I can see the image loading asynchronously while scrolling. The image first pops up half the way up.

The problem is that the recycle mechanism of the ListView acts to fast. I want the Listview to create my listitem more then 200dp away from getting visible. Just a simple preload mechanism to make sure, that the items are fully loaded until they become visible. But I didn't find any clue where and how I could add this buffer in the ListView.

Anyone knows a similar implementation? Did I overlooked something in the docs?

But I'm pretty sure there is no Google implementation of this kind of buffer. Look at the People app. No pre loading...

That's how the recycler works at the moment

[image: How it works now]

Comment: **"But I didn't find any clue where and how I could add this buffer in the ListView."** - It isn't the responsibility of the `ListView` to buffer or pre-load data to be displayed. That's the responsibility of the adapter (or the background code which creates the adapter). That's why the `getView(...)` method is a member of the adapter classes and not the `ListView` class. `ListView` simply calls that method each time it needs to recycle a list item.

Answer (score 1):

About the best you can hope for is to calculate your own "look ahead" indices based on the `getView()` invocations of your `CursorAdapter` subclass and the positions requested. Obviously once `getView()` is called, Android is trying to display the item for that position. If you have it, draw it. If you don't, queue it to be pulled in, *and* start queueing the next N item(s) however deep you want your look-ahead.